# Appium, WebDriver

Tags: android, automation, webdriver, appium

I am new to Appium. I try to execute my selenium script in mobile using Appium. But I got an error like below

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be
>   converted to `WebElement: {ELEMENT=0.5768692365381867-1}`

Code I am using is as below :-

```
AppiumDriver d;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        //Set Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps=new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Celkon A35K Remote");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
        caps.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");

        d = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        d.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
@Test
public void testFBLogin() throws Exception
{
    //Load web page
    d.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    //Enter user name
    d.findElementByName("email").sendKeys("Appium");
    //Enter password
    d.findElementByName("pass").sendKeys("Appium");
    //Click on Login
    d.findElementByName("login").click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
@AfterClass
public void tearDown()
{
    //Close browser
    d.quit();
}`script:
```

Comment: On which line are you getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

below code will work for you , better to test on real device. the only change i have done is "caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");"

```
static AppiumDriver d;
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception
{
    //Set Capabilities
    DesiredCapabilities caps=new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Celkon A35K Remote");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "6");
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");

    d = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    d.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
@Test
public void testFBLogin() throws Exception
{
    //Load web page
    d.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    //Enter user name
    d.findElementByName("email").sendKeys("Appium");
    //Enter password
    d.findElementByName("pass").sendKeys("Appium");
    //Click on Login
    d.findElementByName("login").click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
@AfterClass
public static void tearDown()
{
    //Close browser
    d.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare **AndroidDriver d;** instead of AppiumDriver d.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide more detailed logs to better help you out?

Based on the code you have mentioned, this is what I can think you could do

- Declaring AndroidDriver is not the problem. This should work as it is.
- Just as some people have already mentioned you need to change the

`caps.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");`

to

`caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");`

Saucelabs has great documentation on this here- https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Examples+of+Test+Configuration+Options+for+Website+Tests#ExamplesofTestConfigurationOptionsforWebsiteTests-Mac/OSX/Safari. Check it out

- Finally, try changing the remote address to  "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";

I have issues with using "http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the capability :

```
caps.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
```

by this :

```
caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
```

Appium team did some changes about that:

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md

Answer (score 0):

use
 caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");

You can also replace AppiumDriver to AndroidDriver if your intent only to run this script on Android devices , otherwise if you want to run on IOS and Android both please use Appium.

RemoteWebDriver: This driver class comes directly from the upstream Selenium project. This is a pretty generic driver where initializing the driver means making network requests to a Selenium hub to start a driver session. Since Appium operates on the client-server model, Appium uses this to initialize a driver session. However, directly using the RemoteWebDriver is not recommended since there are other drivers available that offer additional features or convenience functions.

AppiumDriver: This driver class inherits from the RemoteWebDriver class, but it adds in additional functions that are useful in the context of a mobile automation test through the Appium server.

AndroidDriver: This driver class inherits from AppiumDriver, but it adds in additional functions that are useful in the context of a mobile automation test on Android devices through Appium. Only use this driver class if you want to start a test on an Android device or Android emulator.

IOSDriver: This driver class inherits from AppiumDriver, but it adds in additional functions that are useful in the context of a mobile automation test on iOS devices through Appium. Only use this driver class if you want to start a test on an iOS device or iOS emulator.

As you can see, the drivers and their names tie in closely with what they do. When it comes to initializing a driver, only use the Android or IOS drivers.

http://discuss.appium.io/t/what-is-the-use-or-difference-between-androiddriver-iosdriver-appiumdriver-and-remote-webdriver/8750/2

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
AppiumDriver d;
```

With this

```
AndroidDriver <MobileElement> d;
```

Hopefully this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When testing mobile web via Appium please check Appium official site:

(Automating mobile web apps)

https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/#android-mobile-web-automation

```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");

//setup the web driver and launch the webview app.
  URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
  AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);

  driver.get("http://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig");
  WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.id("i_am_an_id"));

  Assert.assertEquals("I am a div", div.getText()); //check the text retrieved matches expected value
  driver.findElement(By.id("comments")).sendKeys("My comment"); //populate the comments field by id.

//close the app.
  driver.quit();
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Change browseName capability to caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
Local host can be anything but I prefer to use http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub

Thanks,
Sudhakar

Answer (score 0):

Change context from native to webview before using selenium in locators.

[How to set context](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-switch-context-from-native-to-webview/14651)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code, it might be useful.

```
    static AppiumDriver d;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        //Set Capabilities

       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");

        d = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities );
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        d.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @Test
    public void testFBLogin() throws Exception
    {
        //Load web page
        d.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        //Enter user name
        d.findElementByName("email").sendKeys("Appium");
        //Enter password
        d.findElementByName("pass").sendKeys("Appium");
        //Click on Login
        d.findElementByName("login").click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown()
    {
        //Close browser
        d.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Desired Capabilities add the following additional Capabilities ,

```
capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "60");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your AppiumDriver variable to:

> AppiumDriver d;

This way you are telling Appium you are searching for a WebElement.

Answer (score -1):

```
DesiredCapabilities ds = new DesiredCapabilities();
ds.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable","E:New folder\\chromedriver.exe");//chrome_driver_path
ds.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"samsung SM-M205F");
ds.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome");
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),ds);
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
driver.findElementByName("email").sendKeys("Appium");
driver.findElementByName("pass").sendKeys("Appium");
driver.findElementByName("login").click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.